# Using NodeJS to create custom Google Assistant triggers

Tags: google-assistant

I am creating a storage system where I'd like to have triggers as:

> Ok Google, Add 5 blue papers to paper box

> Ok google, Find blue papers

> Ok google, take 2 blue papers

Basically custom triggers starting after "Ok Google."

Is there a way to get this right into my app so I can parse it without having "Ok google, talk to APPNAME" first? I see using IFTTT you can do this, but you should be able to do this without? As IFTTT only have 3 free actions.